# TableViewCell not showing up in TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code but I cannot get the TableViewCell to populate. Please help

This is the model file Leave.swift

```
import UIKit

class Leave {
    var startDate: Date!
    var endDate: Date!
    var description: String?


init?(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, description: String) {

    // start date can never ever be later than end date
    if startDate > endDate {
        return nil
    }

    self.startDate = startDate
    self.endDate = endDate
    self.description = description
}
}
```

and I have the following LeaveTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class LeaveTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var leaves = [Leave]()

private func loadUpcomingLeave() {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    let startDate1 = formatter.date(from: "July 5, 2018")
    let endDate1 = formatter.date(from: "July 6, 2018")
    guard let leave1 = Leave(startDate: startDate1!, endDate: endDate1!, description: "testing") else {
        fatalError("Unable to instantiate leave1")
    }
    let startDate2 = formatter.date(from: "August 5, 2018")
    let endDate2 = formatter.date(from: "August 7, 2018")
    guard let leave2 = Leave(startDate: startDate2!, endDate: endDate2!, description: "testing") else {
        fatalError("Unable to instantiate leave1")
    }
    self.leaves += [leave1, leave2]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load the sample data
    loadUpcomingLeave()

    self.tableView.register(LeaveTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "LeaveTableViewCell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.leaves.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Table view cels are reused and should be dequeued using a cell idenifier
    let cellIdentifier = "LeaveTableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? LeaveTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of LeaveTableViewCell.")
    }

    let leave = self.leaves[indexPath.row]
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateStyle = .short
    df.timeStyle = .none
    cell.startDateLabel?.text = df.string(from: leave.startDate)
    cell.endDateLabel?.text = df.string(from: leave.endDate)

    return cell
}
}
```

When I run the app, it displays the table view but none of the cell data. I am expecting 2 roles of leave, that consist of start date and end date. What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you defining the Cells. All the delegates and Protocols for Tableview. please provide complete code.

Comment: Are you setting the `tableView.delegate` and `tableView.dataSource` properties?

Comment: @Skywalker no. How do I set it?

Comment: @soansaini you want to see the `LeaveTableViewCell.swift`??

Comment: Unrelated but why are the properties in the class optional although they are initialized with non-optional values? Remove the exclamation and question marks. Basically **never ever** declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized in an `init` method. If they are supposed to be optional declare them as regular optional (`?`).

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ Are the break points in methods like numberOfRows and Sections get triggered, when you run this code. And Ensure you are using same cellIdentifier in your User Interface, that you have mentioned in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it seems that deleting this line `self.tableView.register(LeaveTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "LeaveTableViewCell")` get the TableViewCell to work cos I have already set the identifier on the Main storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 - Check Do data Exists and coming out from leave CLass**

**Case 2 - If data is Coming from class Leave**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Try using this I think nib you created is not getting registered properly 
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LeaveTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "LeaveTableViewCell")

        loadUpcomingLeave()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: for case one, how do I check?

Comment: Just try printing value to console like print("leave.startDate\(leave.startDate)"). and see do data is really coming out

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.register(LeaveTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "LeaveTableViewCell")

  // Load the sample data
    loadUpcomingLeave()

}

private func loadUpcomingLeave() {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    let startDate1 = formatter.date(from: "July 5, 2018")
    let endDate1 = formatter.date(from: "July 6, 2018")
    guard let leave1 = Leave(startDate: startDate1!, endDate: endDate1!, description: "testing") else {
        fatalError("Unable to instantiate leave1")
    }
    let startDate2 = formatter.date(from: "August 5, 2018")
    let endDate2 = formatter.date(from: "August 7, 2018")
    guard let leave2 = Leave(startDate: startDate2!, endDate: endDate2!, description: "testing") else {
        fatalError("Unable to instantiate leave1")
    }
    self.leaves += [leave1, leave2]
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```